# Concurrent exception for KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We're calling SparkSQL job from Spark streaming. We're getting concurrent exception and Kafka consumer is closed error. Here is code and exception details:

> Kafka consumer code

```
// Start reading messages from Kafka and get DStream
        final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> consumerStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                getJavaStreamingContext(), LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, byte[]>Subscribe(SparkServiceConfParams.AIR.CONSUME_TOPICS,
                        sparkServiceConf.getKafkaConsumeParams()));

        ThreadContext.put(Constants.CommonLiterals.LOGGER_UID_VAR, CommonUtils.loggerUniqueId());
    // Decode each binary message and generate JSON array
    JavaDStream<String> decodedStream = messagesStream.map(new Function<byte[], String>() {}
```

..

```
    // publish generated json gzip to kafka 
    decodedStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void call(JavaRDD<String> jsonRdd4DF) throws Exception {
            //Dataset<Row> json = sparkSession.read().json(jsonRdd4DF);
            if(!jsonRdd4DF.isEmpty()) {
                //JavaRDD<String> jsonRddDF = getJavaSparkContext().parallelize(jsonRdd4DF.collect());
                Dataset<Row> json = sparkSession.read().json(jsonRdd4DF);   

                SparkAIRMainJsonProcessor airMainJsonProcessor = new SparkAIRMainJsonProcessor();

                    AIRDataSetBean processAIRData = airMainJsonProcessor.processAIRData(json, sparkSession);
```

> Error Details

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
```

Finally Kafka consumer closed:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

This consumer has already been closed.
```

Comment: Where is the code that calls the Kafka consumer?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I added code

Comment: What is your question? Seems like a bug in Spark...

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax yes It seems be defect in Spark Streaming kafka connector, Any resolution ?

Comment: Not familiar with Spark -- I would replace Spark with Kafka Streams ;) (disclaimer: I am contributing actively to Kafka Streams)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved using the Cache or Persist option of Spark streaming. In this scenario using cache RDD is not read from Kafka again and issue is resolved. It enables the concurrent usage of stream . But please use wisely cache option.Here is code:

```
JavaDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> cache = consumerStream.cache();
```